# How can i create an object that dynamically updates as data changes in a SQL database?

Tags: javascript, sql, socket.io, visio

This is the situation. I would like to create a diagram, where each of the elements (nodes) would contain some information. This information would dynamically update (AJAX, socket.io,etc.) based on its real-time status. The data would be stored in a SQL database.

Basically, I am using ORION to monitor a bunch of servers, so I have a custom view in a SQL database with the results of its monitoring (CPU, Memory, Networking, etc.) These values are constantly changing.

I want to create what I will call here a "Node". Each "Node", will have different fields (Name, CPU, Memory, Networking, IP Address). So, I would like to be able to have the dynamic values update in real-time to reflect the current status of the machine. Hopefully this clearly shows what I want to do.

I think the best way to create each object would be to give each one a JSON data format, probably use a JavaScript library like Raphael, Joint.js, or Infovis from thejit.org to draw the shapes, and then use a library like socket.io to create a "tcp-like" connection for continuous data streaming.

I have some idea of how this could work with a table, but I want to use a user-friendly GUI. I built a working model using Visio, but would WAY rather keep it all on the web (also very slow refresh rate in Visio).

Please help anyone...

Comment: BTW, I am down for whatever backend...though I would rather not use .NET or ASP or anything microsoft if at all possible. I would really prefer Ruby, Python or ideally Node.js, I figure that the back-end is not really the big issue here, its displaying the data on the front end that I am having trouble with.

Comment: What SQL database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2...its pretty basic...i have access to a custom view which has the data i need. To clarify, I am looking to access the data from that database...an external data source that will feed its data into my "nodes", not a local copy of the database that I created.

Comment: I am guessing i will have to use some sort of ODBC connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce Visio (incl. Viewer) to update data more often than once per minute: change registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Visio\Application\animation` from 60000 to e.g. 5000 (msec). [This sample](http://blog.bvisual.net/2012/01/30/now-then-settle-down/) may be useful.